# Print this text in Scala

Tags: programming-puzzle, scala

Print the following text and nothing else:

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <p>HTML is kinda annoying</p>

  </body>
</html>
I'm happy I'm not a web developer.
```

The catch? Your code must fit the template: `print(<?>)`, where `?` can be any group of characters. You can paste your completed code (with the `print(<>)` part) into [this Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WxSQQcXFTe2vTE0yqOmXnA) to test it. When posting an answer, please mark it as a spoiler.

Here is the sbt configuration:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"
addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.13.0" cross CrossVersion.full)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-language:higherKinds",
  "-Ydelambdafy:inline",
  "-deprecation",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
  "-language:postfixOps"
)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "2.0.0",
  "org.scastie" %% "runtime-scala" % "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

Beware, while the configuration provides one hint, some of these are red herrings.

This is the md5 hash of my solution: `5aa91599e4a8e194b5097b36bdb3dabf`. N.B. it looks like the hash didn't work well with newlines and certain other characters - it may have skipped over them entirely.

Hints:

> Types are involved near the end, at least in the solution I had.
>  `>` is a single token that isn't part of the XML, and it's not a method or field.

hyper-neutrino and pxeger found answers, but they use workarounds that I didn't intend to be used and should have thought of while writing the question. <s>I'll award a [**500 rep bounty**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline/23562#23562) to another answer, provided they meet certain criteria.</s> [This](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0PuNBwskSbmCj2Yx9uDNAw) is the solution.

Comment: So the challenge is essentially try to guess what your solution is?

Comment: @LuisMendo No, other solutions are okay too (preferred, really). The one with comments was just a really trivial one (that I should have disallowed).

Comment: May I ask what the downvotes are for? Is the question not well-specified or interesting enough?

Comment: I downvoted because I find challenge uninteresting, and I don't think it adds anything to the site. As I see it, it's just "try to guess the solution I wrote for this problem". It is not possible to assess the quality of an answer by _objective_, _known-in-advance_ criteria. Note that other challenges with the `programming-puzzle` tag usually include those criteria.

Comment: @LuisMendo ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I can't do much about the challenge seeming uninteresting to people, and I couldn't find any tie-breaker criteria that worked ([code-golf], [fastest-code], etc. don't make much sense here).

Comment: @user can I put a `var`/`val` declaration *before* the print call ?

Comment: @astroide No, everything has to be between the `print(<` and `>)`.

Comment: @user I thought of making something like this `val > = "" ; print(<html>...</html>+ "\nI'm happy...developer." + >)`

Comment: @astroide Oh, I see. I'll add a hint on working around the last `>` to the question.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> print(<html>
>    <body>
>
>      <p>HTML is kinda annoying</p>
>
>    </body>
>  </html>)
>  print("\nI'm happy I'm not a web developer.")
>  //>)
> ```

Probably not intended :)

Comment: This is infuriating. +1 >(. If another answer with my intended solution doesn't pop up in a month or so, I'll accept this, but right now, I'm too angry to do so.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> print(<html>
>    <body>
>
>      <p>HTML is kinda annoying</p>
>
>    </body>
>  </html> + "\nI'm happy I'm not a web developer.")
>  def x = (<x />)
> ```
>
> [Try it on Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4UMBzYxrTMOlpGs1Zmf5ZQ)

Comment: Still not my intended solution, but nice find :P (I'll start a bounty in two days)